# Call javascript onclick() inside of a logic:iterate tag in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts, struts-tags

```
<logic:iterate id="empList" name="search" property="empList" indexId="index">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <bean:write name="empList" property="empID"/>
            </td>

            <td>
                <bean:write name="empList" property="firstName"/>
            </td>

            <td>
                <bean:write name="empList" property="lastName"/>
            </td>



            <td> 
                <html:button property="View" value="View" onclick="viewPage()"/>
                <html:button property="Update" value="Update" onclick="updateUser()"/>
                <html:button property="Delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteUser()"/>
            </td>

        </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

I want to call javascript with empID.
Can anybody help me to get proper syntax for the code.

Comment: Hi sridha, if i use  viewPage('empID') it's pass as a string not value...
I need to pass value like 1st iter empId = 100, 2nd iter empId = 200.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Its an sample for you.

```
<html:checkbox name="someList" property="someStatus" indexed="true"
 onclick="<%="javascript: changeSomeCheckBox("+index+")"%>" />
```

Comment: Hi Hariharan, After use your code i am getting below exception <br><br> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/viewedit.jsp(68,58) Attribute value "javascript: viewPage("+index+")" is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value

Comment: Refer sample example here http://www.mail-archive.com/struts-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg83720.html

Comment: im unable to predict where it went wrong so refer the above link

Answer (score 0):

`<html:checkbox name="someList" property="someStatus" indexed="true"
 onclick="<%="javascript: changeSomeCheckBox('+index+')"%>" />`
Try single quote